# Directing audio output to a Bluetooth speaker in iOS 7 without using MPVolumeView

Tags: ios, bluetooth, air-native-extension

Is it possible to direct audio output to a Bluetooth speaker in iOS 7 without using the [`MPVolumeView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) UI class?  (iOS 7 is required for my project.)

I need to do this because I am working on a native extension which will allow an Adobe Air application to send audio over A2DP.  As I understand it native extensions preclude the use of UI classes so I cannot use [`MPVolumeView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

There is an [`overrideOutputAudioPort:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioSession/overrideOutputAudioPort%3aerror%3a) method on `AVAudioSession` but the only [available overrides](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/AVAudioSessionPortOverride) are `AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone` and `AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker` (for the built-in speaker and microphone).

The documentation states that the [`setOutputDataSource:error`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioSession/setOutputDataSource%3aerror%3a) method needs to use an object from the [`outputDataSources`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioSession/outputDataSources) array which is only supported on “certain USB accessories”.

I understand that Apple prefers applications to allow the user free choice of audio output device but if I cannot use `MPVolumeView` how can I offer this?  I’d be happy to code the UI in ActionScript if I could just read and set the available options in the Objective-C extension but it seems to be impossible at present.

Have I missed anything or are there any other options I could use?  Any thoughts or comments appreciated.

**Edit:**
I was wrong to say that "native extensions preclude the use of UI classes".  I am now displaying the MPVolumeView in my AIR application.  However I would still like to know if it is possible to take more direct control of the audio output route.